# Ejecutar script en fecha y hora de Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar

Quisiera saber como ejecutar una secuencia de comandos (script /  myFunction) creada en una planilla de Google Sheets (ActivaCalendar.gsheet) utilizando como activador el calendario de Google.

He añadido un activador y seleccionado el origen del evento desde calendario y registrado mi cuenta de correo

[[image: Configuracion Activador1]

Pero no logro hacer que la función `myFunction` se ejecute

Sucede lo siguiente:

- Al crear un evento o modificarlo en el calendario default, en cualquier dia y horario, el script se ejecuta, siempre. Tengo varios calendarios pero esto sucede solo en el de default
- Cuando llega la hora del evento, el script no se ejecuta. El TimeZone es correcto
- Probe creando un calendario con el nombre de la planilla (ActivaCalendar) y un evento con el nombre `myFunction` pero no ha funcionado. Esto ultimo me pareció que podía ser una posibilidad para que funcione.

La idea es ejecutar el script dos o tres veces al año pero no siempre en el mismo dia del mes.

Estoy seguro de que estoy haciendo algo mal u omitiendo algun paso pero realmente no puedo encontrar la solucion.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario.
Con todo respeto, creo que el problema esta bien claro. 
No se trata de un tema de codigo (por eso no he puesto nada) sino del funcionamiento del activador calendario. 
He agregado una foto especifica de la seccion donde, entiendo, se debe configurar el activador pero se presentan los problemas que he descripto en la consulta.
Realmente no sabria que mas agregar

Answer (score 0):

Si te es posible te sugiero usar tu cuenta de Google en inglés ya que la traducción de la interface suele causar confusiones. En el caso de la captura de pantalla hay varias etiquetas mal traducidas que quizás te han llevado a confusiones acerca de cómo funcionan los activadores.

Los actividores de *evento de calendario* se ejectuan cuando un *evento de calendario* se crea, actualiza, edita o se elimina.

Para crear un activador que se ejecute en una determinada fecha o con una determinada frecuencia debes de usar otro tipo de activador, basado en tiempo, en inglés *time-driven trigger*. La interface de configuración de activadores basados en tiempo permiten configurar algunos parámetros, pero otros sólo se pueden configurar mediante programación.

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén. Utilizare la cuenta en ing

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén.
Estudiaré acerca de los otros activadores para encontrar la manera de hacer ejecuciones trimestrales en el primer lunes de dicho trimestre.
Tambien tendre en cuenta para futuras consultas tu comentarioa cerca de utilizar la cuenta en ingles.
Muy buena suerte y, de nuevo, muchas gracias
Omar